# I want to cache a frame, and then render another scene on the basis of this frame, how to do it?

Tags: three.js

I want to cache a frame, and then render another scene on the basis of this frame, how to do it?

I set two scenes, one is the physical scene, one for the cursor scene, because the physical scene may not change.

Now I use 2 canvases, one on top, and use a transparent background to solve the problem.

```
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    canvas.style.position = "absolute"
    canvas.style.zIndex = "100px";

    canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none";

    canvas.style.width = "100%";
    canvas.style.height = "100%";

    canvas.style.left = "0px";
    canvas.style.top = "0px";

    el.appendChild(canvas);

    render = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, clearColor: 0, alpha: true })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to render one scene, and then render a second scene on top of the first. This is actually pretty easy to do, although you can just as easily cause undesired results by performing the wrong actions.

First, tell your renderer not to auto-clear its buffers:

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: canvas, alpha: true });
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

Next, you need to *manually* clear the buffers before rendering the first scene. If you don't clear here, then the previous image will remain on the canvas.

```
renderer.clear();
renderer.render(scene1, camera1);
```

With the first scene rendered, you need to ensure your second scene will render on top of the first. Calling `renderer.clear();` would cause it to erase the first scene. Instead, you only want to clear the depth buffer. This removes any depth information the renderer had previously, and will cause it to draw all new pixels on top of the old ones.

```
renderer.clearDepth();
renderer.render(scene2, camera2);
```

Failing to clear the depth buffer would mean the renderer would remember where all the `scene1` objects are (spatially), and it would render the `scene2` objects as if they occupied the same space as `scene1`.

At this point, you should see the second scene rendered on top of the first, and they're both drawn to the same canvas.

If you have any questions, or would like me to expand on any of the steps above, please leave a comment below.

three.js r88

**UPDATE**

This seems like a hacky way to do it, so if anyone has better ideas, please chime in. What I've done in the code below is make rendering the background to be optional, and using the first rendered scene as the background behind the canvas. In the case of my example, I'm allowing the background to render once every ~1s. The red cube can still be manipulated at the full framerate allowed by `requestAnimationFrame`.

A couple things to note:

If you want to capture an image of your full render, it MUST be captured after a render where `renderWithBackground === true`. In all other cases, the canvas will actually only contain the contents of `scene2`.

Also, the first frame renders with a black background, and I'm not sure why. I don't have any more time at the moment to continue debugging it.

```js
var renderer, scene1, scene2, camera1, camera2, controls, bgCube, fgCube;

var renderWithBackground = true;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
  FOV = 35,
  NEAR = 1,
  FAR = 1000;

function populateScenes() {
  var cubeGeo1 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(15, 15, 15),
    cubeMat1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "green"
    });
  bgCube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo1, cubeMat1);
  scene1.add(bgCube);

  var cubeGeo2 = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(5, 5, 5),
    cubeMat2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: "red"
    });
  fgCube = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo2, cubeMat2);
  scene2.add(fgCube);
}

function init() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.autoClear = false;

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  document.body.style.margin = "0";
  document.body.style.padding = "0";

  scene1 = new THREE.Scene();
  scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

  camera1 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
  camera1.position.z = 50;
  scene1.add(camera1);

  camera2 = camera1.clone();
  scene2.add(camera2);

  controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera2, renderer.domElement);
  controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
  controls.rotateSpeed = 3;

  var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
  camera1.add(light);
  camera2.add(light.clone());

  setInterval(function() {
    renderWithBackground = true;
  }, 1000);

  resize();
  window.onresize = resize;

  populateScenes();

  animate();
}

function resize() {
  WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
  HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
  if (renderer && camera1 && camera2 && controls) {
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    camera1.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera1.updateProjectionMatrix();
    camera2.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();
    controls.handleResize();
  }
}

function render() {
  renderer.clear();
  if (renderWithBackground) {
    renderWithBackground = false;
    renderer.render(scene1, camera1);
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + renderer.domElement.toDataURL() + "')";
    renderer.clearDepth();
  }
  renderer.render(scene2, camera2);
}

function animate() {
  bgCube.rotation.x += 0.001;
  bgCube.rotation.y += 0.002;
  bgCube.rotation.z += 0.003;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
  controls.update();
}

function threeReady() {
  init();
}

(function() {
  function addScript(url, callback) {
    callback = callback || function() {};
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.addEventListener("load", callback);
    script.setAttribute("src", url);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function() {
    addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js", function() {
      addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function() {
        threeReady();
      })
    })
  })
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know this rendering method.
The problem I'm facing now is that the first scene now does not need to be rendered repeatedly, but the second one is changing.
In order to optimize performance, I want to stop rendering Scene1 and update Scene2.

(And very sorry, my English is not good.)

Comment: @xcad I've updated my answer. (And don't worry, your English is fine.)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Clever. Your method reduces the complexity of the background scene, though it still has to render that scene every frame. I thought about saving off a render target, and then just dumping its bytes into the canvas each frame, but I think that might only work for 2D contexts. Do you know if the `ArrayBufferView` returned by `glcontext.readPixels` is also writable?

Comment: I've tried 'WebGlRenderTarget' but I can not find a way to set it on the canvas as a background.

Comment: @TheJim01 Using canvas and then copying 'DataURL', there is a performance problem with doing this, as I tested it for 10ms per execution

Comment: @xcad This is why I wanted to move the pixel buffers around directly. Have you tried Rabbid76's solution?

Comment: @TheJim01  I know what WebGLRenderTarget he said, I want to render it directly to the canvas, but I can not find a way to do that.

Comment: @WestLangley hi

Comment: I think if the pixel is being read, the speed is not fast, because if it is a 1000 * 1000 canvas, then it will have to loop 1000,000 times.

Comment: @xcad In Rabbid's example, there is also only one canvas. The render target is used to create a texture for a plane. That plane gets rendered to the canvas first, and then the foreground objects get rendered. The texture of the canvas only updates when you want it to (at intervals in the example).

Comment: This seems to be an interesting way, he took a mesh as a background, I think this should be able to solve the problem.